# How does the author reached that solution by integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

[image]

I cannot understand how the author got the final solution.

What I see in the first integral that after solving the inner integral gives  $\displaystyle \int_0^z \lambda e^{-\lambda x}(-e^{-\mu y})|_0^x dx =  \int_0^z \lambda e^{-\lambda x}(1-e^{-\mu x}) dx= \int_0^z \left( \lambda e^{-\lambda x} - e^{-(\lambda+\mu) x}\right)dx= (-e^{-\lambda x})|_0^z+\frac{e^{-(\lambda+\mu) x}}{\lambda+\mu}|_0^z=(1-e^{-\lambda z})+\frac{1}{\lambda+\mu}(e^{-(\lambda+\mu) z})$.

The second integral would be

$\displaystyle \int_t^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda x}(-e^{-\mu y})|_0^z dx = \int_t^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda x}(1-e^{-\mu z}) dx=\int_t^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx -  e^{-\mu z}\int_t^\infty  e^{-\lambda x} dx = (-e^{-\lambda x})|_t^\infty-(e^{-\mu z}/\lambda)(-e^{-\lambda x})|_t^\infty = (e^{-\lambda t}) (1-(e^{-\mu z}/\lambda))$.

But adding up the integrals does not yield the expected solution.

Comment: This looks pretty dubious because there's a $t$ in the second summand but not the first, and no $t$ in the result.

Comment: 'z' and 't' do look similar when handwritten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistakes are written in red on the screen copy below :

[image]

Also, there is a typo in the initial equation : $t$ should be $z$.

Comment: I fixed the mistakes and replaced $t$ by $z$. It works :) .